# How can I handle if the embedded application is down(getting 500/400) on IFrame in angular9

Tags: angular, iframe

As per my requirement, I have to load an application which is of a different domain URL on Iframe from matDialog. The happyflow works fine but when application is down the application will be blank. In this case needs to show the error message and close button on matDialog pop up, when user clicks on close button the popup should close. How can I detect the embedded application is failed to load?

Could anyone can help on this?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have access to the embedded website? In order for you to know if the iframe has loaded correctly, you'll need to emit a message from the embedded website and set up a listener for it on your website.

Have a look at the Window.postMessage() function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Comment: You could kind of ping the website before loading it and see if you get an OK Status Code.

Comment: @El-Mo Thanks for reply, we don't have control over the application

Comment: MarkusDeibel, Thanks for the reply. you mean to say AJAX request ?

Comment: I tried with onLoad() event, and by checking with the contents (find(<body>). in both scenarios the contents getting loaded. I am not sure what exactly to check to handle this scenario.